# How to add typescript rules in NextJs Project without losing next/core-web-vitals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, eslint

I have a typescript NextJS project with the following `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
{
    "extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
}
```

I would like to add some additional typescript rules (like do [not allow the type any (`no-explicit-any`)](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any/)).

1. I added `npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`
2. Extend the config by the `no-explicit-any` rule, updated the parser and added the plugin.

```json
{
    "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "warn"
    }
}
```

3. Now the `no-explicit-any` works. However all the default rules from the `next/core-web-vitals` are not working anymore.

So I can either have the next or use the typescript-eslint rules. How can I use booth?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to include both presets in within an array in a single `"extends"` property, similar to this:

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    "next/core-web-vitals"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json",
  }
}
```